# Unable to receive Push notification on IOS 8

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios8

I've an apps with push notification working well on it. After i upgrade device to iOS8, i unable to receive push notification on my device, even with correct device token, taken with function `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` .

The push notification is working perfectly on iOS < 8.

i do add a function `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` for compatible with iOS8. I able to get prompted request permission for push notification dialog, and able to get device token string. Sadly, i still get no luck in this.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

https://support.pagerduty.com/hc/en-us/articles/203238050-Receiving-push-notifications-on-iOS-8

I have the same issue too

read this : As of September 19, 2014, our engineers confirmed with Apple that this is a known issue with the iOS 8 upgrade.

Khodor

Answer (score 0):

You should see and read session number 713 of Apple #WWDC2014.
It has got all the information regarding the IOS8 Push Notification actions.

Here is a link for this. Watch "What's new in ios notifications" videos : 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

Comment: can you further elaborate what is that? sorry, im new in iOS

Comment: I am providing you a link for this. Watch "What's new in ios notifications" videos. Here is the link : https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/